# Some trouble with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is this html

```
  <div class='title centered'>SCE</div>
  <div class='description'>
    Magna tristique pulvinar porta montes, scelerisque
    odio montes porta habitasse, ut, arcu scelerisque vel, pellentesque
  </div>
```

I need to fade childer div (description) after clicking on parent (title).

```
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').fadeOut(fadeTime);
  })
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try being more specific in the title. you will get better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this just once on your page, balalakshmi's answer will work. If you have more than one, go with this:

```
$('.title').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.description').fadeOut(fadeTime);
})
```

Note the use of [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), which looks at the next element at the same level in the dom,instead of `find` which looks for decedents.

Finally, if the effect you are really trying to achieve is a toggle on title click, use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) or one of the many fadeToggle plugins.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with this?

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    $('.description').fadeOut(fadeTime);
  })
```

Comment: There are a lot of such blocks. Action must be executed only in one of them (clicked)

Answer (score 1):

Use $.next() to find the next element and work with that

```
$('.title').click( function() {
    $(this).next('.description').fadeOut( fadeTime );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrong thing is that in your code "description" is not a child of "title".

I think balalakshmi's answer will do the job for you or you can use if you don't want to use "description" class as a selector:

```
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeOut(fadeTime);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$("#t_sce").click(function() {
    $("#d_sce").fadeOut(fadeTime);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it must be used without #id. 
Fixed in Question

Answer (score 0):

I would have another parent div wrap around it.

```
<div class='item'>
   <div class='title centered'>SCE</div>
      <div class='description'>
        Magna tristique pulvinar porta montes, scelerisque
        odio montes porta habitasse, ut, arcu scelerisque vel, pellentesque
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I would call using

```
$('.title').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div.item').find('.description').fadeOut(fadeTime);
})
```

This code is not depended on the order of the discription div.